# Differences in scaling values

Tags: svm

Every tutorial that I read says it´s important to scale data before training.

What is the difference between scaling in ranges [0,1], [-1,1] and [-5,5] ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any difference. The [goals of scaling](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) are 1) to make sure that all features have similar magnitude, to avoid the svm loss function only caring about large features, and 2) to avoid computational problems with large feature magnitudes.

All three scalings you suggested satisfy #1. Arguably [-1,1] does the best job of being right in the middle of the range of signed floats (for #2), but any differences between these three scalings will be trivial.

I should mention that if your features have a broad distribution (e.g. a Gaussian distribution) rather than coming from a fixed interval, scaling to a fixed range may not be a good idea, since then the extreme values will be at -1 and 1 and most data points will be very close to zero. A better approach in that case is to scale the data such that the mean is zero and the variance is one, ensuring that the majority of the features will have values of order $10^0$. As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) suggested below, if the situation is even worse and you have a non-Gaussian distribution with significant outliers, then you may want to normalize based on another measure of dispersion like [IQR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range).

As was brought up in the comments, changing the scaling of your features may also require changing the scale of other hyperparameters, such as the soft-margin cost.

Comment: chris, what is long-tailed feature distribution? Can you give me an example ? Other question: I scaled my data in [-1,1], and than [-5,5]. The parameters of both classification technique (for example, SVM) theorically will be the same ?

Comment: I tried to clarify in the answer - I'm just talking about any feature distribution where there are rare occurrences that are far from the mean. Using these rare maximum and minimum values for the scaling will give poor results.

And yes, the parameters should be the same (possibly up to an overall scale factor, depending on the model).

Comment: +1 This answer clearly outlines and discusses the relevant principles. Concerning your recommendation to standardize to unit variance to avoid being influenced by outliers, it would seem much better to standardize to a robust estimate of dispersion, such as an IQR, because compared to the SD that will be relatively unaffected by outlying data.

Comment: I've added an edit. I was using "outliers" a little too loosely - I just meant that the rare extreme values in a Gaussian distribution would compress your scaling in a bad way. True "outliers" would make the situation even worse and could make variance a bad dispersion measure, as you suggested.

Comment: Its sounds clearly to me. I'm doing something wrong, because my data is giving results too different between scaling the training set with [-1,1] and [-5,5]. My set have 6 features, one of it is between [1,30], the other ones is [0.5,1.5]. Can this only one feature makes this noise after scaling ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You should scale each feature separately to the same range, e.g. [-1,1]. The relative scales of the original features (e.g. that one can be 30 times larger) should have no effect on the scaled values, since each each is scaled separately.

Comment: That's what I'm doing (as default svm-scale from libSVM). I can't see yet. I gotta completely different parameters and results using [-1,1] and [-5,5].

Comment: It's possible that you will also have to scale the "c" soft-margin hyperparameter by 1/5^2 as well, since the scale of the "w" variable in the cost function has changed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Soft_margin

Comment: Thats sounds nice, I will try.

Comment: Chris, no. I agree that it has changed, but, for example: with [-5,5] a C=64/g=0.5 gives 0.017 mse, while to achieve 0.022 mse with [-1,1], I have to do a C=2048/g=2. Almost the same results, really different in complexity, and, it is the same data.

Comment: Is 'g' referring to a RBF kernel hyperparameter? I was assuming this was a linear SVM, it's less clear to me exactly how both g and C should scale in this case.

Anyway, I guess I'm not quite seeing the issue here - pick a scaling, use a validation set to tune hyperparameters, and test. The end result shouldn't be very scaling-dependent. Trying to figure out the hyperparameter scalings is interesting (at least to me) but a little beside the point, no?

Comment: Chris, I'm sorry, it's about RBF. Don't worry, thank you very much for help.